# Always "allow assignment of unique numeric IDs for sharing web layers"

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

Every time I try to publish a feature layer to ArcGIS Online, I get the error message "00374: Unique numeric IDs are not assigned".

The fix is to check the  "Allow assignment of unique numeric IDs for sharing web layers" option on the Map Properties page.

[image]

Is there a way to set this option globally, so it automatically applies to every new project?

Comment: Good question.  It beats me why "on" is not the default for this option.  Sure, there are legitimate cases for having it off.  But I would assume that the people who want to manage those IDs manually are vastly in the minority.

Comment: I don't believe there is currently an option to enable this on as default in ArcPro 3.1. This question is ripe for being an [Idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/arcgis-ideas) on the esri community forum.